# Install swagger-codegen via npm on Windows OS

Tags: angular, typescript, client, swagger-codegen

I've generated my client typescript/angular2 language using https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen  via a Java Command.

But i would like to generate my client typescript/angular2 using an npm command not a java command.

Example :

```
  npm install swagger-codegen -g
  swagger-codegen generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l
  typescript-angular2 -o c:\temp\angular2_api_client
```

I'am using windows 8.1 OS. 
I didn't find swagger-codegen command to install with npm.

Comment: @suraj swagger-js ia dynamic JS API client, not a code generator.

Comment: @mahdi-kallel can you tell us more on why you want to generate code using NPM module instead of JAR?

Comment: `npm` consists of primarily of js libraries and all its scripts deal with javascript. So what does it mean using NPM to generate with a Java library?

Comment: Our Server should not have java command . we are obliged to use only npm.

Comment: You can generate code with HTTP requests via https://generator.swagger.io. Please refer to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to generate a client API for Angular 2 TypeScript without java command but using node command.

Example node script to generate typescript angular client from swagger.yaml. Note that we use http. Request cannot verify the first certificate if using https (at the time of writing this)

This is app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var jsYaml = require('js-yaml');
var request = require('request');
var unzip = require('unzip2');

var codeGenEndpoint = 'http://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients';
var language = 'typescript-angular2';

fs.readFile(path.resolve('swagger.yaml'), 'utf8', function (error, yaml) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    var swaggerObj = jsYaml.load(yaml);

    var postBody = {
        spec: swaggerObj,
        options: {
            modelPropertyNaming: 'camelCase',
            apiPackage: 'api.clients.settings',
            modelPackage: 'api.clients.settings'
        }
    };

    request.post({
        url: codeGenEndpoint + '/' + language,
        body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }

        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            throw new Error('Response code was not 200. ' + body)
        }

        var responseObj = JSON.parse(body);

        request({
            url: responseObj.link,
            encoding: null
        }).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'src/client/js/codegen/settingsApi'}));
    });
});
```

I just set variable `language` to `'typescript-angular2`'.
After that `node app.js`

For the list of available client languages just visit http://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients

And for more details: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/FAQ
section Generator Service

Comment: Thanks for this! If you are on Node 12 or higher, use `node-unzip-2` instead of `unzip2`. Also change the protocol on the codegen endpoint to `https` and use `https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients` to get a list of compatible clients.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sh
npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g
```